# Can dial smooth-pairing worked?

Tags: cobalt

I can pair the phone with tv by url paremeter setting.

example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/tv?pairingCode=xxxxx
```

However, when I launch cobalt first, and then pairing by pushing the cast icon on phone.

It can not paring tv and phone.

Can the smooth-pairing worked on Cobalt?

Answer (score 1):

Smooth pairing doesn't work yet due to Cobalt's security model. This should be fixed by the end of Q1, in the next several weeks.